# SQL Server 2008 R2: From a SQL Server Log file, how do I find out what is causing an event

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backup

> [image: More focused screen shot of SQL Server log]

**Problem:**

The attached image is a screen shot of the SQL Server log showing an event that happens every Tuesday at around 1:20 AM. This event is causing the transaction log backup chain to break and all subsequent transaction log backups to fail.

**Question:**

How can I find out what is causing/doing this?

Comment: You mean all the replication activity centered on the same database isn't a clue? What other information are you looking for? You can look at trace / extended events, for example.

Comment: Can you look at the jobs configured on server. Make sure you look at codes you can , I guess somewhere in code it is getting changed

Comment: @Shanky yes, I suspect there is some ill-advised task in a job somewhere that shrinks the log file, and accomplishes that by changing from full to simple and back. Smoking gun is it took three minutes to perform the second change.

Answer (score 1):

For the purpose of not leaving this question open and in hopes that it helps someone in the future, I wanted to detail the steps I followed to solve my problem. 
In following the advice given about running a trace around the time the Recovery model is changed, I found that there was indeed a task that was shrinking the log.

[image: Found the culprit]

**Summary**

Using SQL Server Profiler trace allowed me to find out what was causing the problem.